# How to deploy a python script with flask which uses pywin32 library?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, pywin32

I want to know how to deploy a python script with flask which uses pywin32 library.

I have made an app locally in windows for the processing of excel files hence i have used the pywin32 library given by python to excess excel files.

But while deploying this flask app using versel it shows error with the pywin32 library as

```
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==306"
```

Is there any other platform to host flask applications with this library or I am doing anything wrong. If you have any doubt regarding this question, please ask.

Comment: The versel servers are running on a Linux OS, so the pywin32 package will not work.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it's simple just go with any hosting service which gives you windows platform to host your app like heroku (paid), Amazon AWS - which I used for my app for free.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).